# multiple user accounts on same ps3

Tags: ps3

my daughter insists that it will be a disaster if her sister creates a seperate account on the ps3. I need help and the wisdom of Solomen here, can anyone out there help

Comment: What is the main concern here?  It's quite hard to give a good answer without the question being clarified - but my four housemates and I all have an account on one PS3 and haven't had any problems at all

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I'm still not entirely sure of the potential concerns here, it's safe to say that it **wont be a disaster** - at least from a technical standpoint.  As for avoiding sibling spats, who knows!

Having multiple accounts allows for:

- Individual separated savegames, potentially useful if a game only has a finite number of save slots per installation
- Individual theme settings for PS3 menus and backgrounds etc.
- Individual Playstation Network (PSN) accounts

  - Individual trophy achievement
  - Individual friend lists
- From your point of view allows you to set individual parental controls should you wish

When the PS3 boots, you are prompted to chose between accounts, perhaps taking a second or two of time but beyond that doesn't really change much.